# PYTHON: Doesn't increment position of a list element

Tags: python, list, iteration

```
sequence = [1, 1, 1, 2, 3]

sequence2 = []
k = 0
if len(sequence) == 2 or len(sequence) == 1:
    print('Great!')
else:
    for element in range(0, (len(sequence))):
        sequence2.append(sequence[element])
        sq = sequence2.index(sequence2[-1])
        print(sequence2, sq)
        if sequence2 == sorted(sequence2):
            print('This is good thus far:', sequence2)
        else:
            print(sequence2[sq-1], sequence2[sq])
            print(sequence2.index(sequence2[-1]))
            if sequence2[sq-1] >= sequence2[sq]:
                sequence2.pop(sequence2.index(sequence2[sq - 1]))
                print('We poppoed an element')
                print(sequence2)
                k = k+1
if k >= 2:
    print(sequence2)
    print('This doesnt work')
else:
    print('Works properly!')
```

OUTPUT:

```
[1] 0  
This is good thus far: [1]  
[1, 1] 0  
This is good thus far: [1, 1]  
[1, 1, 1] 0  
This is good thus far: [1, 1, 1]  
[1, 1, 1, 2] 3  
This is good thus far: [1, 1, 1, 2]  
[1, 1, 1, 2, 3] 4  
This is good thus far: [1, 1, 1, 2, 3]  
Works properly!
```

Hey guys; I've got a question why does the program gives me back 0 for sq, the first 3 times it iterates? Shouldn't it give me 0, 1, 2..? I can't wrap my head around it for the past 2 days...

Comment: What is the first index of `1` in `[1, 1, 1]`?

Comment: You're searching for the first occurrence of `1` in the list.  Why do you expect it to return something other than 0?  What did you not understand from the documentation?

Comment: You can read more about list functions here: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html

Answer (score 4):

Because `sequence2.index(value)` returns the first instance of 'value' , and you have repeated 1's in sequence2

Comment: Ahhhh.. I wasn't aware of that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Because you have 3 '1s' and it show the first if you tried with different data